# failed to curl https url from Privoxy over tor

Tags: ssl, https, proxy

I have installed privoxy over TOR on a centos server, I can curl successfully simple http page, but failed to get https page like https://www.google.com. 
Here is my tor conf:

```
SocksBindAddress 127.0.0.1
SocksPort 10010
SocksPolicy accept *
#Log notice syslog
Log info file /var/log/tor/tor1.log
RunAsDaemon 1
User digi-tor
CircuitBuildTimeout 30
NumEntryGuards 6
KeepalivePeriod 60
NewCircuitPeriod 15
DataDirectory /var/lib/tor1
PidFile /var/run/tor/tor-1.pid
```

And my privoxy config, I added/modified these lines:

```
listen-address  127.0.0.1:11010
forward-socks5t   /               127.0.0.1:10010 .
```

When I make a curl for an https page:

```
curl -x http://127.0.0.1:11010  -s 'https://www/linkedin.com'
```

I get an error on privoxy log

```
Crunch: Forwarding failed: www:443
```

Comment: Have you checked that Tor is running? Can you paste the log after Tor has started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:10010 https://www.linkedin.com
```

and take a look at further tutorial [here](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/ssh-socks-and-curl/)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about the Google page failing to load but your LinkedIn URL is broken.

It is
`https://www/linkedin.com`
It should be
`https://www.linkedin.com`